# Unexpected token. A constructor, method, accessor, or property was expected. - typescript function

Tags: node.js, typescript, api, express

I am new to typescript, I am trying to learn how to use JSON Web Token to authenticate a typescript API but I am getting this error whenever I do npm start.

I am getting unexpected token at Function

How can I fix this error and I can I get JSON auth on this test API?

I am sure that most of my errors are in between the //start of test and //end of test comment

```
export class UsersController {
  constructor(
    @inject(UsersBindings.USERS_SERVICE)
    public usersService: UsersService,
  ) { }

// Start of test
  @get('/api', generateSpec('Get Api list'))
  async apiList() {
    return ("This is a sample gold API");
  }

  @post('/api/posts', verifyToken, (req, res) => {  
    jwt.verify(req.token, 'secretkey', (err, authData) => {
      if(err) {
        res.sendStatus(403);
      } else {
        res.json({
          message: 'Post created now...',
        });
      }
    });
  });

  function verifyToken(req, res, next) {
    const bearerHeader = req.headers['authorization'];
    if(typeof bearerHeader !== 'undefined') {
      const bearer = bearerHeader.split(' ');
      const bearerToken = bearer[1];
      req.token = bearerToken;
      next();
    } else {
      res.sendStatus(403);
    }

  }
// End of test

  @get('/users/{id}', generateSpec('Get user profile'))
  async getUserProfile(@param.path.string('id') id: string): Promise<Users> {
    return this.usersService.getUser(id);
  }

  @post('/user', generateSpec('Create new user'))
  async createUser(
    @requestBody(generateRequestBody(TeacherProfile))
    userRegisterCredentials: IRegisterUserCredentials): Promise<Users> {
    return await this.usersService.createUser(userRegisterCredentials);
  }
}
```

Comment: It is not advisable to provide your full code. Minimize and encapsulate the code for your specific problem, and provide it clearly reproducible. ref: [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Thank you, I have made some modifications to the question

Comment: You need to debug and locate the issue firstly and provide the full error stack.